# Removing custom posts type posts from array, based on ACF date-time value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to show posts by the date time field in ACF. My posts are sorted so that the closest to todays date is the first in the list and posts with a date in the past, that post is not included in the array.

I tried the different solutions i were able to find in here with no luck.

What my code looks like:

PHP Code:-

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'arrangement',
    'meta_query'    => array(
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'date',
                        'compare'   => '>=',
                        'value'     => $today,
                    'type'  => 'DATETIME',
                    )
            ),
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'          => 'date',
    'meta_type'         => 'DATE'
));
```

When I am showing the posts:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

EDIT: With the code above, the post that has a date in the past is shown in the while loop, but no data from the post is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, ACF saves the datetime fields as a timestamp internally, so you'd have to change your meta query to a numeric comparison and use time() instead of your formatted date time.

Comment: so changing value to: time() and type to NUMERIC ? just tried that out with the outcome being that alle data from the posts didn't get rendered.

Comment: In the meta_query, yes.
Have you looked at the data in $prefix_postmeta? Search for meta-key = 'date' and ...
I just realized, it might be that ACF saves them as timestamps with milliseconds, so value should compare to time() with three zeros added, e.g. `"value" => time() . "000"`, but only a look into the table will tell for sure.